# Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using following codes in nodejs server to Formats a string to the ISO8601 standard using moment

```
var dateStr = "2016-5-20 17:25:45";
var urecordtime=moment(dateStr).toISOString();
```

But i am getting

> "Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info."

How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the format as a second parameter, so that the library doesn't need to guess the actual format:

```
var m = moment("2016-5-20 17:25:45", "YYYY-M-D HH:mm:ss");
var s = m.toISOString();
```

Sources:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

Answer (score 0):

This **warning** message basically says that the **Date you are passing in the moment needs a 'format'** although your date is formatted. Please have a look at the [link](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/).

I was fetching the day from the date. After the conversion, At that time i got this warning message.

- **Warning prone code:** moment($("#payPeriodDate").val()).toDate().getDate()
- **Warning safe code:** moment($("#payPeriodDate").val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate().getDate();

You need to provide the format and warning should be disappear from the console..!!

Thanks for reading, Happy coding..!!